# Control gets cut off with anchor setting of WinForm at different DPIs

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2022

I'm not sure how else to explain this other than to show it in screeshots.

I'm designing my text box control:

[image]

to be linked on both sides of the resizable parent window. I did it with the use of the `Anchor` property:

[image]

(I should say that the visual studio designer on my laptop is running at 150% DPI setting.)

This window runs fine on a normal size screen. But then if I run it on a small screen in a VM, the control gets cut off:

[image]

And even when I try to make its parent window wider, that control still remains outside of its boundaries:

[image]

(I'm running this VM at 100% DPI setting.)

What shall I do to fix this?

Comment: What is the parent of the `TextBox`? if its not a `Form`, then make sure you `DockStyle.Fill` it. And you should not scale the display of the developing environment. `100%` when you design. And before all of that, is your app Dpi-Aware?

Comment: Make your app DpiAware (`PerMonitorV2`), set `AutoScaleMode = Dpi` -- Design at 100% scale. Visual Studio issues a warning when you don't. You could ignore it, but... -- You could use VS as *example*: it provides means to scale its UI's Font, in case the Font size is too small/large in specific scenarios. -- Note that the TextBox `AutoSize` property acts on the Width of the Control.

Comment: Thanks guys. The problem was that Visual Studio's designer (even he latest version in VS 2022) is not compatible with DPIs other than 100%. When I made VS run at 100% DPI with an awful upscaling by the OS renderer (that made it look all blurry) I was able to build my project and controls started showing as expected. Before that I had to manually disable all `Anchor` properties via code edits and move controls to the right position and then re-enable anchors, because while being incompatible with high DPIs the designer also messed up all my control layouts. That fixed the issue.